# Значение dataset jquery и dataset JS отличаются

Tags: javascript, jquery, dataset

Сегодня я столкнулся с непонятной для меня вещью. Возможно, это связано со спецификой Jquery, но мне очень интересно и в то же время непонятно почему так.

Если проделать следующую последовательность действий:

1. Нажать "Кнопка 1"
2. Нажать "Жми"

Здесь мы видим $multy = multyJS = 1

3. Нажать "Кнопка 2"
4. Нажать "Жми"

И вот здесь $multy = 1, а multyJS = 2. Причем data-multy у элемента popup = 2.

Собственно, почему так?

```js
let popup = document.querySelector('.popup');

setDataToPopup = (button) => {
popup.dataset.multy = button.dataset.multy;
console.log(popup.dataset.multy);
}

$('body').on('click', '.popup .popup-button', function () {
let $popup = $(this).closest('.popup');
let $multy = $popup.data('multy');
console.log('data-multy from Jquery ' + $multy);
let multyJS = document.querySelector('.popup').dataset.multy;
console.log('data-multy from JS ' + multyJS);


})

document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => setDataToPopup(button))
})
```

```css
.popup {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.button-one {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup-button">Жми</div>
</div>

<div class="button button-one" data-multy='1'>Кнопка 1 </div>
<div class="button" data-multy='2'>Кнопка 2 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery кэширует датасет, поэтому не рекомендуется смешивать обращения `$(element).data` и `element.dataset`.

https://api.jquery.com/data/

> An element's data-* attributes are retrieved the first time the data()
> method is invoked upon it, and then are no longer accessed or mutated
> (all values are stored internally by jQuery).

то есть

> Атрибуты `data-` элемента извлекаются при первом вызове метода
> `data()` для него, а затем больше не читаются и не изменяются (все
> значения хранятся внутри jQuery).

Также: https://api.jquery.com/removeData/

Comment: Могу ли я каким-то образом получить актуальное значение data-multy на jquery? Или только на чистом js можно

Comment: @Alexander Вы уже прочитали https://api.jquery.com/removeData/ ?

Comment: @Alexander нет, не читал, спасибо